# Хранение большого объема данных

Tags: администрирование

Имеется веб сервер с CRM системой, в которой планируется прикреплять большое число файлов. Объем данных предполагается превысить 10ТБ. Как лучше организовать хранение такого большого объема данных? Веб сервер расположен на удаленном хостинге, где максимальный размер дискового пространства составляет 6Тб.

Comment: хостинг не AWS?

Comment: нет на renter.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решаем эту проблему уже не первый год. Объем данных у нас правда в 1000 раз больше но может пригодится:

Все объекты разбиты на территории с собственным ДЦ.

В ДЦ установлен:

- JBOD 90TB на HDD дисках
- cache сервер на ssd 20TB для быстрой раздачи файлов

Но есть очень много сторонних фирм предлагающих "холодное" хранение данных с не ограниченной закачкой и платной скачкой данных

- https://www.rackspace.com/cloud/files
- https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/5gy8w2/alternatives_to_s3_and_rackspace_cloud_files/

Comment: можете рассказать как вы объединили дисковый массив ? использовали RAID или LVM ?

Comment: Используем физический RAID. Сервера Supermicro.

Answer (score 0):

Вы может использовать сервиз Amazon S3 или аналогичный ему.

S3 позволяет хранить неограниченные объемы данных (они ограничены суммой которую вы готовы тратить), обеспечивать безопасный доступ к ним (ссылки с ограничением), легкое масштабированием и пр.